# Mongodb find the Consecutive Failure Count

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a dataset like this:

```
{
    ip: 1.1.1.1,
    process: 123,
    type: failure,
    date: 2021-04-01
},
{
    ip: 1.1.1.2,
    process: 124,
    type: failure,
    date: 2021-03-01
},
{
    ip: 1.1.1.1,
    process: 123,
    type: failure,
    date: 2021-02-01
},
{
    ip: 1.1.1.1,
    process: 123,
    type: success,
    date: 2021-01-01
}
```

How can I get the consecutive failure count for a given ip address and process? For example, given the dataset above, if I was to check how many times ip 1.1.1.1 has failed for process 123 before the last success I should get 2. However if the success record was the last record then I should get 0.

What I have so far is:

```
activityLog.find([
  {
    $match: {
      ip: "1.1.1.1",
      process: "123"
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      date: -1,
    },
  },
  {
    $limit: 10,
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      type: 1,
    },
  },
]);
```

This gives me a list of all types - sorted and matched

Answer (score 0):

You can do the followings in an aggregation pipeline:

1. find the previous success record
2. do a self-lookup to find the fail records after the previous success record
3. do the count of the lookup of step 2

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      ip: "1.1.1.1",
      process: "123",
      type: "success"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      date: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      let: {
        ip: "$ip",
        process: "$process",
        date: "$date"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$ip",
                    "$$ip"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$process",
                    "$$process"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $lt: [
                    "$date",
                    "$$date"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$type",
                    "success"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            date: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 1
        }
      ],
      "as": "lastSuccess"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$lastSuccess",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      let: {
        ip: "$ip",
        process: "$process",
        date: {
          $ifNull: [
            "$lastSuccess.date",
            ISODate("9999-12-31")
          ]
        }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$ip",
                    "$$ip"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$process",
                    "$$process"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $gte: [
                    "$date",
                    "$$date"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$type",
                    "failure"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "previousFailures"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "lastFailuresCount": {
        $size: "$previousFailures"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6V3xvQSeLUy) for your reference

Comment: Thanks @ray for this but adding a latest success event doesn’t seem to yield the right result. Have a look at https://mongoplayground.net/p/scaI3u4t4Zn

Comment: @VishalRastogi sorry for the mistake. I have updated the answer to find previous failures using a default max last success date, so that there wont have other falsely matched failures record for the 2021-01-01 success record in your latest testing dataset